A way to concat data from child rows of parent row of a pivot table

I have a large pivot table with the following data. The bold text is the parent row of data and the following years (non-bold data) are the child data of the parent row. Is it possible in excel or python with a formula to concat all the child row data into a one row in the following column next to the parent row. I want to be able to make the dataset look like the following.


If it's a fixed amount of child rows, you can use a clever If statements and Textjoin to combine them on a column to the side and remove the rows you don't need.

It isn't a fixed amount of child rows. The amount of child rows varies. Some don't have any child rows, others have rows ranging from 1-4 child rows. Would the function still work the same?

hmm in that case it likely wouldn't. However if you put them into their own columns, and repeat row labels you can validate whether that parent row is the same as the one above it and if it is, combine with the one above until it hits the next one. I'll see if I can draft up an answer quick

Has your question been resolved?

So first, I would setup the pivot table so the child and parent are in their own individual columns. You can do this in the pivot table "design" under "report layout" by showing "Tabular Form". Then "Repeat All Item labels" (in the same design tab) and remove subtotals.
I added a column next to my 'pivot table' where I check the row we're in's parent cell against the row above it. If they're the same we're going to combine the child cell of this row with the one above, otherwise we're just going to take this row's child cell.
Then we'll have something like what we see on the left of my image, the third column being the formula.
Then we take the parent cells (I used a unique function, you can copy if you prefer that), and used an xlookup's exact match but in reverse order to pull the last instance for each, giving you the dataset you want.

